# CSS property value from JSON

Tags: html, css, json

I'm a newbie in the html/css/javascript world, and I'm trying to do something but can't figure out how. I have a simple background image with some markers buttons on it, these markers have each their own class in CSS where I assigned them a top and left value to position them above the image. The next step would be reading those values from a JSON file, instead of me directly writing them in CSS, but I can't figure out how to do it.

My JSON file looks something like this:

```
[{ "name" : "marker1", "top" : "150px", "left" : "50px" }, {"name" : "marker2", "top" : "200px", "left" : "100px" }]
```

while my buttons look like this one:

```
<button class="marker1" onclick="togglePopup('box1')"><ion-icon size="large" name="add-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+assign+position+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on StackOverflow!

This is a trivial solution to the question you asked. I don't know if you use a JavaScript framework or not. If you do, consider refactoring the code that creates the button. If not, this solution will still show you how to achieve the desired behaviour.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .marker {
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const json = JSON.parse(`{
            "markers": [
                { "name": "marker1", "top": "150px", "left": "50px" },
                { "name": "marker2", "top": "200px", "left": "100px" }
            ]
        }`);

        for (const marker of json.markers) {
            const button = document.createElement("button");

            // styling
            const sides = ["top", "right", "bottom", "left"];
            sides.forEach(side => {
                if (marker.hasOwnProperty(side)) {
                    button.style[side] = marker[side];
                }
            });

            // class
            button.classList.add("marker");
            button.classList.add(marker.name);

            // icon
            const icon = document.createElement("ion-icon");
            icon.setAttribute("size", "large");
            icon.setAttribute("name", "add-circle-outline");

            button.appendChild(icon);
            document.body.appendChild(button);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```